# Running parallel async tasks?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, concurrency

So I've been searching StackOverflow/Google for different methods of running multiple async tasks concurrently. There seemed to be quite the debate between different methods and I just wanted to get some clarification. I'm writing a program to execute a JSON POST request until the server returns a status code of 200. Let's say I want to run 5 of theses tasks in parallel until one returns a status code of 200. Please try not to stray away from the topic, I have no control over the server! Here's my current code,

```
    static bool status = false;
    public static async Task getSessionAsync() {
        while(!status) { ... } 
    }
    public static async Task doMoreStuff() {
       ...
    }
    public static async Task RunAsync() 
    {
        await getSessionAsync ();
        await doMoreStuff();
    }
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        Task.WhenAll(RunAsync()).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
```

Basically, I'm wondering if it's wrong for me to approach it like this,

```
    public static async Task RunAsync() 
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            await getSessionAsync ();
        }
        await doMoreStuff();
    }
```

Comment: You've to post JSON until server returns status code 200 is ok, but why do you need to do it in parallel?

Comment: It smells like a bruteforce...

Comment: Both of your approaches run the requests in a sequence, not in parallel - the `await` ensures that. If you need to run them in parallel (which sounds quite fishy, *especially* with a POST request), you need to `await` the tasks *after* you run all the `getSessionAsync` "instances"; probably using something like `Task.WhenAny` or just `await`ing in a sequence, depending what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: By all means I am not attempting to "hack" or do any unethical programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not run in parallel:

```
public static async Task RunAsync() 
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        await getSessionAsync ();
    }
    await doMoreStuff();
}
```

You have to use `Task.WhenAny()`

```
public static async Task RunAsync() 
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        tasks.Add(getSessionAsync());
    }
    await Task.WhenAny(tasks);
    await doMoreStuff();
}
```

If you do not need your current context (i.e. when you are writing a Library and not Frontend code), don't forget to use `ConfigureAwait(false)` after each await.

Comment: Hoping to pick your brain one last time, so let's say getSessionAsync() finishes executing it's task. It shouldn't be bad practice to start another task inside another task right? I want to move 'await doMoreStuff()' to inside the getSessionAsync() method. I'm referencing an article I'm reading and it's giving me guidelines of do's and don'ts. I just wanted to clarify.

Comment: You can have as many awaits as you want inside a Task, I have never heard of it being bad practice, nor is it feasible to have only one await in one Task. Mind however having a method/Task consisting of too many lines is bad practice.

Comment: Thanks! My current Task methods are just initializing a basic variable, and doing a comparison and return. My goal was to be as modular as possible. I did run into an issue where I ran 10 threads, and it seemed to have run sequentially. I'm not sure if it was a fluke. When I ran 3 threads, it worked in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

```
private Task<MySession> GetSessionAsync()
{
    // ...
}
```

**Option 1**

`Task.WhenAny`

```
var session = await await Task.WhenAny(Enumerable.Range(0, 5).Select(_ => GetSessionAsync()));
```

**Option 2**

You could use the Rx LINQ method called `Amb` which will observe only the first Observable that returns something.

```
var session = await Enumerable.Range(0, 5).Select(_ => GetSessionAsync().ToObservable()).Amb().ToTask();
```